# Is calling a static method from an instance method thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety

Is calling the instance method `RenderHelp` in the example below thread safe? It calls static methods of the `Helper` class but does not use any static variables of that class.
If 2 or more different instances of `Helper` (each running on different threads) call `RenderHelp`, can there **ever** be a problem?

```
public class Helper
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    // other fields

    static int[] Multiply(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        if (a.Length == b.Length) return a.Zip(b, (a1, b2) => a1 * b2).ToArray();
        else return null;
    }

    static int[] Add(int[] a, int[] b)
    {
        if (a.Length == b.Length) return a.Zip(b, (a1, b2) => a1 + b2).ToArray();
        else return null;
    }

    public int[] RenderHelp(string help, int[]a, int[] b)
    {
        if (help == "Add".ToLower()) { return Add(a,b); }
        else if (help == "Multiply".ToLower()) { return Multiply(a,b); }
        else return null;
    }
}
```

Links to relevant MSDN or other docs will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

*Also why doesn't stackoverflow properly format `get`, as in above?

Comment: A method can't tell who is calling it. Therefore it makes no difference whether the caller is static or instance. It can't affect anything.

Comment: But an instance method belongs to the instance object. Isn't a copy of it made at instance object creation?

Comment: Sounds like you should study some C# fundamentals. It's dangerous to program without understanding basic operating principles of your language. Stack Overflow is a good place for beginner questions as well, so feel free to ask.

Comment: @AAA - Instance methods are **not** copied when an instance is created. All that is created are the fields/properties of the class.

Comment: Sorry, I mean one operated on instances while the other belonged to the class. But do you get my question? I noticed that most other questions like this on stackoverflow use a static method of a static class being called on different threads. Here we have a non-static class with a static method being called on different threads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is thread-safe. Threading issues generally occur around sharing resources, which you're not doing here. This is following the [Microsoft threading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f857xew0(v=vs.71).aspx) suggestions:

> Avoid providing static methods that alter static state. In common
>   server scenarios, static state is shared across requests, which means
>   multiple threads can execute that code at the same time. This opens up
>   the possibility for threading bugs. Consider using a design pattern
>   that encapsulates data into instances that are not shared across
>   requests.

If you were to use a static variable somewhere in these functions, then no it wouldn't be thread safe unless you started putting locking or other thread safe ways of handling that variable.

Comment: if I get you right, even though I am sending reference variables, it is thread safe? for instance if two `Helper` instances call their respective `RenderHelp` methods simultaneously, and both `RenderHelp` methods try to access the same static method `Add`, is it possible that one of them could set `int[] a` and the other `int[] b`?

Comment: @AAA: Unless the `a` or `b` array variables passed into `RenderHelp()` are the exact same ones passed in via 2 different threads, then you'll have no problem. The code within `Add()` will operate on the variables given to it, and there will be no pollution or cross-over of these variables on different threads.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just wanted to confirm this before implementing in bigger code.

Comment: @AAA it it helped please feel free to upvote and/or accept this as the answer :)

Comment: I wanted to upvote, but I can't... not until I have 15 reputation points.